# Displaying Timer for blackberry app

Tags: java, blackberry

i want to diaplay a timer in my application for blackberry.When the application starts at the top the timer will b displayed in the form of 00:00,& it will keep on increasing as long as the apllication is on.So i hav written code for that thng,bt i am getting null pointer exception,can anyone help me plz.